# How to chain APIs using Azure API management

Tags: web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

How to chain multiple APIs on the same URL using Azure API management?

I have two APIs the user store and that user recources api.

I want to build rest api so resources will related to user.

Mycompany/users/dani@gmail.com/resources.

User store api is mycompany/users
Resources api is mycompany/resources.

I dont want to build additional service that will consolidate this two apis.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single API in API Management that points to multiple different backend APIs.  Use the `set-backend-service` policy to change the backend API for certain operations.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I search for.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can use 'send-request' policy, that will call another API endpoint and store the result in declared variable. This is what worked for me.

In my case I had hit another URL after getting response of first APIs. Same can be done in inbound policy also before getting response and similarly you can hit multiple APIs.

Policy snippet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I followed steps provided in this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/api-aggregation-using-azure-apim link and able to combine two API responses within one API call.

It tells how to aggregate or chain more than one API responses in API management

Comment: Although your answer could be 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...